# Installing mlocate on mac OS 10.7

Tags: locate, file-search

I'm a beginner in using Linux. I'm trying to use the command "locate". Once I use this command, I get an error that says the locate database should be created. I used the command below to create that database, but I still get the same error:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
```

I tried so many things including installing locate, but the commands work in Ubuntu seem not to work in mac os. Does anybody know what the issue is?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "updatedb" command does not work on my mac either !

Comment: Does waiting help?  It will take a while from the launch until the index file is actually there.  Depending on the size of your disk(s), expect to spend anywhere between ten minutes and a couple of hours for the initial indexing.

Comment: Hi @tripleee, thanks so much. Yep, it's now working.

Answer (score 9):

Although `locate` et al. are available for macOS, the native approach is to use Spotlight, which is enabled by default. From the command line you can use `mdfind`:

```
$ mdfind [keyword]
```

One huge advantage over `locate` is that it searches file contents and metadata too, not just filenames. If you'd like to restrict the search to filenames only use the parameter `-name`:

```
$ mdfind --name [filename]
```

Comment: Often you don't want to search the contents but just the filenames and searching the contents too can get slow? or is there a way to exclude that? In linux I use grep to search contents, which is a little tedious `grep -rnw '/path/to/start/of/search/' -e 'search_string'`